# How to install oracle jdk11 in Alpine linux docker image?

Tags: java, docker, segmentation-fault, java-11, alpine-linux

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc:latest

ADD jdk-11.0.6_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /usr/java

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-11.0.6
ENV PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

When I run the command `java -version` in the container, I get this segfault:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does `uname -a` show?

Comment: `uname -a` shows:Linux b64957345808 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 Linux

Answer (score 46):

`frolvlad/alpine-glibc` is a glibc-enabled Alpine Linux image, and `jdk-11.0.6_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` is likely a mainland Linux JDK glibc build. In theory, this should be fine, but there may be subtle glibc incompatibilities that cause this.

If you're looking for Java 11 on Alpine, you could just grab the vanilla Alpine 3.11 image, then install the `openjdk11` package on top:

```
sudo docker run -it alpine:3.11

# apk add openjdk11

# java -version
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-alpine-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-alpine-r0, mixed mode)
```

If you need 11.0.6 specifically, install the latest `openjdk11` package of the `edge/community` repository instead:

`apk add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but for some reason, my program uses Oracle jdk11, not openjdk11, and I have not carefully tested my program on openjdk11.

Comment: Hi @Brucewayne-TheGeekKiller, could you update on what isn't working? I'll try to update the answer with relevant information.

Comment: Thank you! Any available package can be found here https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openjdk11&branch=v3.11 It is also suggested to update package list first, i.e. `apk --update-cache add openjdk11`  https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Update_the_Package_list

Comment: Do we need to login into http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine repo?

Answer (score 12):

From a working container

```
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN  apk update \
  && apk upgrade \
  && apk add ca-certificates \
  && update-ca-certificates \
  && apk add --update coreutils && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*   \ 
  && apk add --update openjdk11 tzdata curl unzip bash \
  && apk add --no-cache nss \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```