# Alpine with jdk11 as base docker image

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, alpine-linux, openjdk-11

I have a base `Dockerfile` used by a bunch of services, looking like this:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.11_9-alpine-slim
```

There were some [security fixes for Linux Alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.11.12-3.12.8.-3.13.6-released.html), and I'd like to include them in my base image. Looking for a new image on [AdoptOpenJDK's official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk), I've found that these tags are deprecated as of 1st August 2021 in favour of the [Eclipse Temurin](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin/) project.

Eclipse Temurin does not have an alpine-based jdk11 image. Do I...

1. Use the 11-jdk-focal from Temurin?
2. Build my own alpine image and add jdk11 to it?
3. Use any other alternative provider?

References:

- [How to install oracle jdk11 in Alpine linux docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015712/1774643)
- [Installing openjdk 11 on alpine:3.9](https://serverfault.com/a/960783)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update Jan 2020**

Eclipse Temurin has launched alpine versions. :)

https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin?tab=tags&page=1&name=alpine

---

My solution for now is to use alpine as base image and install openjdk with apk, as explained here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459967/1774643

```
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN  apk update \
  && apk upgrade \
  && apk add --update openjdk11 tzdata curl unzip bash \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```